# css grid object-fit: cover not working in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

For some reasons in firefox using object-fit: cover the image doesn't cover the entire parent div but works in Chrome

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpt6bs2o/) so that it's easier to see the error

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="cards">
      <img draggable="false" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/952379/pexels-photo-952379.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
    <div class="ytSimilarityPctLabel">
      <div class="cardHeader">
        <div>
          <div id="similarity">0%</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dots">
          <div class="dot dotActive"></div>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imageDescription">
      <div class="card_subs">
        <div class="card_text_tags"><span>Pewdiepie</span><span>MrBeast</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card_bio">bio</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
* {
    font-family: ProximaNova,sans-serif;
}

.cards {
    transform: translate(0px);
    grid-area: cards;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-rows: 5% 67% 28%;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    z-index: 5;

}

.grid-container > div {
    text-align: center;
}

.imageDescription {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 65% 35%;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-areas: "card_subs" "card_bio";
    padding: 1vh;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}

.cards img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 25px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 128%;
}

.ytSimilarityPctLabel {
    display: grid;
}

.main {
    grid-area: main;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 5vh 75vh 20vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,minmax(0,100vw));
    grid-template-areas: ". . ." ". cards ." ". buttons .";
    background-color: #f6f7fa;
}
```

I tried many things but couldn't get it to work properly on firefox.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Actually it works as expected in FF not in chrome, the row in which the `img` is in has height `5%`

Comment: How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your end result is, However I will attempt to explain what is happening

You've put `.card` inside `.main` in the `cards` grid area, Naturally `.cards` now should take the height of that row, because `.cards`'s height is `auto` *(Because you didn't specefy any height)*

In `CSS Grid` `auto` gets stretched (default value for alignment properties) Firefox understands that implicitly and assigns the height of that grid area to `.card`, However Chrome seems to need to be told explicitly.

```css
* {
    font-family: ProximaNova,sans-serif;
}

.cards {
    transform: translate(0px);
    grid-area: cards;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-rows: 5% 67% 28%;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    z-index: 5;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid-container > div {
    text-align: center;
}

.imageDescription {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 65% 35%;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-areas: "card_subs" "card_bio";
    padding: 1vh;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}

.cards img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 25px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 128%;
}

.ytSimilarityPctLabel {
    display: grid;
}

.main {
    grid-area: main;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 5vh 75vh 20vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,minmax(0,100vw));
    grid-template-areas: ". . ." ". cards ." ". buttons .";
    background-color: #f6f7fa;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="cards">
      <img draggable="false" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/952379/pexels-photo-952379.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
    <div class="ytSimilarityPctLabel">
      <div class="cardHeader">
        <div>
          <div id="similarity">0%</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dots">
          <div class="dot dotActive"></div>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imageDescription">
      <div class="card_subs">
        <div class="card_text_tags"><span>Pewdiepie</span><span>MrBeast</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card_bio">bio</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**In Firefox:** the height is known, any percentage value based on the height will be known

**In Chrome:** the height is auto, any percentage value based on the height will be `0` so `grid-template-rows: 5% 67% 28%;` becomes `grid-template-rows: 0% 0% 0%;` However a height must be defined, It is then defined by the tallest element, Then we calculate percentages from it.

**Demo**

```css
[grid]{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:50% 60% 50%;
  /* height is omitted so it defaults to auto*/
  
}

[tall]{
  height:100px;
}



/* Styling to be ignored*/
[grid]>div{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div grid>
  <div style="background:red;"></div>
  <div style="background:orange;"></div>
  <div style="background:pink;" tall> I'm the tallest sibling height:100px <br> However the row i'm in is 50% of my height</div>
</div>
```

---

Now because `.card` doesn't have any height, All the height constraints for the `<img>` are ignored with respect to it's aspect ratio defined by the width constraints,so it spills out.

Leave a comment for the expected end result and i will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: The expected end result is the result you get on chrome opening the jsfiddle

Comment: @BaptisteKnacky If you want to have an image as a background for `.cards` why not specify it as `background:;` and get rid of that `5%` row?

Comment: You can add the image as a css variable with react and use it in the css, or you can try position it behind everything else inside `.card` https://jsfiddle.net/wybkhpvL/